# Can AX manage database replica/mirroring?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

In the future my company will open two remote office, so we will have 3 single office that can access to Dynamics AX.

What is the best 'scenario' I can configure?

Is it possible to have 3 AOS (one per office) that access to 3 physical database (one per office) that syncronize each other, so if the HDSL line drop, each office can work indipendetely ?

Or it is impossible, so any AOS must access to the same 'single' database?

As you can see my main 'concern' is about DSL Line and not about 'server hardware' failure. Where we have headquarters, we have worst DSL line, so our concern is 'If the line drop, how to allow remote office to continue to work ?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your AOS's and DB servers should be centralized, I would also have remote access to terminal servers from your 3 offices. Your AOS and DBs should be connected via fibre in your server room, I think having them geographically far apart would only be okay if you had access to some serious fibre links.

Your issue seems to be your HDSL. Think about investing in leased lines, backup via a 2nd line directed to a different exchange, and even 3g dongles or adsl modems with 3g backup (you can get modems with a usb port for a 3g dongle). If you are connecting remotely via a term server or maybe a citrix desktop, 3g would be an adequate backup strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal server is your best bet.  If your "main office" has bad DSL, perhaps one of your other offices can be considered your "AX Main Office" where servers and reliability will be.

AX [does support database mirroring](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axinthefield/archive/2011/01/18/database-mirroring-with-dynamics-ax.aspx), but not for your purposes.  It's for failover.  You could also do a VPN tunnel where your other networks could all use local clients on the VPN.